# creating UI elements on NSOperationQueue non-main queues causes strange behavior

Tags: ios, ios5, user-interface, nsoperationqueue

I had some code that created and added `UIView` subviews via a queue created by `[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]`, and it led to strangely laggy behavior. Subviews were only added after abnormally long delays.

But then I switched to using `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` for these parts, and responsiveness turned normal.

I would just like an explanation for the laggy behavior I saw using the first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple doc

> **Threads and Your User Interface**
>
> If your application has a graphical user interface, it is recommended that you receive
> user-related events and initiate interface updatesfrom your
> application’s main thread. **This approach helps avoid synchronization
> issues associated with handling user events and drawing window
> content.** Some frameworks,such as Cocoa, generally require this
> behavior, but even for those that do not, keeping this behavior on the
> main thread hasthe advantage of simplifying the logic for managing
> your user interface. There are a few notable exceptions where it is
> advantageous to perform graphical operations from other threads. For
> example, the QuickTime API includes a number of operationsthat can be
> performed from secondary threads, including opening movie files,
> rendering movie files, compressing movie files, and importing and
> exporting images. Similarly, in Carbon and Cocoa you can use secondary
> threads to create and process images and perform other image-related
> calculations. Using secondary threads for these operations can greatly
> increase performance. **If you are not sure about a particular graphical
> operation though, plan on doing it from your main thread**

In addition, UI classes are not thread-safe according to the [thread programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Multithreading.pdf).

**So, avoid to update the UI from a thread different from the main thread.**

If you run an `NSOperation` (within a queue) you could update your UI (for example after having download some data required for your app lifecycle) performing a method in the main thread like the following:

```
-(void)main {

    // e.g the delegate could be the controller that has the view that you want to update
    if (delegate) {

        NSURL *url = [delegate urlForDownloadOperation:self];
        if ( nil == url ) return;
        self.downloadedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        
        // e.g. rather than invoking processImage directly on the delegate, ensure that the method draw the image on the main thread
        [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processImage:) 
            withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Or you could send a notification to the component that need to update the UI like:

```
- (void)main {

   NSURL *url = [delegate urlForDownloadOperation:self];
   if ( nil == url ) return;
   self.downloadedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   
   // e.g. send a notificatio to inform some components that it is ready to update the UI with some content
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"importData" object:self];
}
```

The component that needs to update the UI will register for that notification like

```
- (void)processImage:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processImage:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    // update the UI here, you are running on the main thread
}
```