# iOS: NSOperationQueue: Secondary queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I would like to receive some data to the server in an asynchronous way and avoiding to overload the [App UI performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421219/creating-ui-elements-on-nsoperationqueue-non-main-queues-causes-strange-behavior). Hence would like to send tasks to the secondary queue and not the main one.

This is my current solution which uses the **"main queue"** (**[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]** which I understand slows down the performance):

```
-(NSDictionary*) fetchURL:(NSString*)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCONTACTSINFOURL]];

    __block BOOL hasError = FALSE;
    __block NSDictionary *json;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
                           {
                               //Verify type of connection error

                               json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];
                               NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);



                           }];

    if (hasError) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] suspend];
        return nil;
    }
    return json;
}
```

In order to use the secondary queue, and avoid overloading the UI and App performance, **is it ok to allocate a shared NSOperationQueue and refer to that?** Or is there some other "better" class or method to achieve this?

This would be my improved solution using a secondary NSOperationQueue:

Creating a secondary queue:

```
    NSOperationQueue* otherQueue = [NSOperationQueue init];
```

Using the other (secondary) queue:

```
....
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:otherQueue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
....
```

}

Is this correct? Or is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: I think what you are doing is fine. You might want to think about keeping hold of the queue in your object and using the same one for each call. Or possibly keeping it as a static in the class. This will potentially make debugging easier later.

Comment: Thanks. I have inserted the queue in a static class "NetworkManager" which I can access from everywhere in the App. The idea is to suspend the secondary queue if there is an error for example no server available, re-add the task to the secondary queue and at the same time trigger off a recursive thread that executues every few milliseconds and that will verify the availability of the server and when the server is back up will stop and resume the queue. Would this be a sensible approach?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here..? [NSURLConnection sendAsyn...] uses it's own queue behind the scenes to make the request. The queue that you are passing in is only used to execute the completion handler when the connection completes. Not sure why you want to stop getting callbacks when there is an error? Did you think suspending it would stop making requests? Are you trying to achieve some mechanism to constantly know if you are connected to your server?

Comment: Yes and not only that. I am basically implementing a small chat App. So I need a queue for messages to send to the server. So for this reason if a message is not being sent due to a server offline error I would like to pause the messages queue and resume it once the connection is back up. Any more precise tutorial/suggestion will be wellcome :-)

Comment: Give me a few mins, will post an answer so that I can include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

... following on from the comments...

The NSURLConnection method

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]
```

allows you to specify the queue that the completion handler will be called on when the connection is complete. If you suspend this queue you will not stop the requests being sent, you will just stop getting callbacks when they are done. You may want to think about doing this slightly differently...

NSOperation is great, but I tend to prefer going straight for GCD (NSOperation is just a nice obj-c wrapper on the top) if you are hard-set on using NSOperations let me know and i'll add some advice for that.

I assume that you have some kind of manager class that handles all of your server communication? If not, I would recommend that you do, and have it as a singleton.

```
@ interface ChatManager : NSObject
    + (ChatManager *)sharedManager;
@end

@implementation ChatManager {
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue;
    dispatch_queue_t postQueue;
}
+ (ChatManager *)sharedManager {
    // This is just the standard apple pattern for creating a singleton
    static SCAddressBookManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[SCAddressBookManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Create a dispatch queue that will run requests one after another, you could make this concurrent but that may cause messages to be lost when you suspend
        fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        postQueue = dispatch_queue_create("post_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
}

- (NSDictionary *)fetchURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // In here we will dispatch to our queue and so that the 
    dispatch_async(fetchQueue, ^{
        NSURLRequest = // create your request
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        // Check for error
        if (error) dispatch_suspend(fetchQueue); // this suspends the queue that is making the calls to the server, so will stop attempting to send messages when you have an error - you should start pinging to see when you come back online here too, and then use dispatch_resume(fetchQueue) to get it going again!
        else {
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
            return json; // ??
        }
    });
}

- (NSDictionary *)postURL:(NSURL *)url data:(NSData *)bodyData {
    // In here we will dispatch to our queue and so that the 
    dispatch_async(postQueue, ^{
        /*
          Make your post request.
        */
        // Check for error
        if (error) dispatch_suspend(postQueue);
        else {
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
            return json; // ??
        }
    });
}

@end
```

You may also need to use

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do stuff on the main thread here
};
```

if you need to make delegate style callbacks to the main thread!

This is a basic idea on how I would have things setup to try and achieve what you are going for... feel free to let me know if any of this doesn't make sense to you..?

As a side note, I have assumed that for whatever reason you need to have a simple http interface for your server. The much better approach would be to have a persistent socket open between the app and your server, and then you can push data up and down at will. A socket with a heartbeat would also let you know when your connection has gone down. Not sure if maybe you would like me to elaborate on this option some more...

Comment: I disagree. NSOperationQueue is simpler and more high-level. I think it's a better choice than GCD unless you have very specific requirements, but OP didn't mention any.

Comment: @MichałCiuba I agree with what you're saying, I just happen to be more comfortable/familiar with GCD so it was easier to write up an answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to have more than one dispatch queue? One to GET/FETCH and one to POST?

Comment: Absolutely, just have two ivars and a separate method for get/fetch and post. You can, within reason, have as many as you like!

Comment: Just made an edit, I also added how to call back to the main thread if you need it.